# What is the SQL command for a many to many relationship together with one to many?

Tags: sql, database

The following is my sample:

[image]

How do List All `items` belonging to `building` X, with a `category` of Y?
I am unsure what to look for (is it joins? inner outer?). I think my difficulty in finding the answer via google is because I do not know how to properly phrase the question. Any help please.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `exists`?

```
select i.*
from items i
where exists (select 1
              from building b
              where b.id = i.building_id and b.name = 'X'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from category_has_item chi join
                   category c
                   on c.category_id = chi.id
              where chi.item_id = i.id and c.category = 'Y'
             );
```

In your case, you can also reasonably express this directly with `join`s:

```
select i.*
from items i join
     buildings b
     on i.building_id = b.id join
     category_has_item chi
     on chi.item_id = i.id join
     category c
     on chi.category_id = c.id 
where b.name = 'X' and c.category = 'Y';
```

I think this is essentially the same in your case, assuming there are no duplicates in `category_has_item`.  If both relationships were many-to-many, then the first approach would probably be faster.

Comment: I will use your second example. thanks. So it was a join it seems. I just didn't know what to join on what. Thanks, will use 2nd example. And in the linking-table, there are no duplicates. I just forgot to put a primary key in the diagram.